# QML animation for Menus

Tags: qt, animation, qml, qt5, contextmenu

I want to animate a context menu during popup.I've used the [Behavior](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-behavior.html) QML type but that doesn't work for me:

```
Menu {
    Behavior on width{
        NumberAnimation{
            duration: 200
        }
    }
    Behavior on height{
        NumberAnimation{
            duration: 200
        }
    }


    id: contextMenu
    MenuItem { text: "Cut" }
    MenuSeparator{}
    MenuItem { text: "Copy" }
    MenuItem { text: "Paste" }
}
```

Also using `contentHeight` or `implicitHeight` instead of `height` doesn't work either.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some properties for `Menu` component, that contains transitions. Such as `enter` and `exit`. You can find all properties [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-menu-members.html)

I suppose you want to achieve transition of width and height from 0 to whatever it is. But it seems like Menu has preset width and heigh. So you need to implicitly set `from` and `to` properties for animations. For example:

```
Menu {
    id: contextMenu
    enter: Transition {
        ParallelAnimation {
            NumberAnimation { property: "height"; from: 0; to: contextMenu.implicitHeight; duration: 200 }
            NumberAnimation { property: "width"; from: 0; to: contextMenu.implicitWidth; duration: 200 }
        }
    }

    MenuItem { text: "Cut" }
    MenuSeparator{}
    MenuItem { text: "Copy" }
    MenuItem { text: "Paste" }
}
```

Comment: This won't work if you define an `exit` transition that is the reverse of the `enter` transition. For it to work in that case you'd need to declare two properties that store the initial `width` and `height` so that they're not overwritten. The code above happens to work because the `NumberAnimation` stores the `to` value as it was before the animation started, but it's pretty fragile once you start introducing other transitions.

Answer (score 3):

`Menu` is a `Popup`, and all popups support [`enter`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html#enter-prop) and [`exit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html#exit-prop) transitions. To animate a menu opening, for example:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Button {
        text: "Open menu"
        onClicked: contextMenu.open()
    }

    Menu {
        id: contextMenu

        enter: Transition {
            ParallelAnimation {
                NumberAnimation { property: "width"; from: 0.0; to: contextMenu.implicitWidth }
                NumberAnimation { property: "height"; from: 0.0; to: contextMenu.implicitHeight }
            }
        }

        MenuItem { text: "Cut" }
        MenuSeparator {}
        MenuItem { text: "Copy" }
        MenuItem { text: "Paste" }
    }
}
```

The benefit of using `implicitWidth` and `implicitHeight` is that you won't have to declare properties to store the initial values of `width` and `height` in order to avoid them being overwritten by other animations, as you would with the accepted answer.

Comment: Both answers are correct but I prefer the answer of @Maxim Skvortsov because of being slightly more useful.Thanks :)